# DatabaseClasses.pas(192): F2084 Internal Error: AV081C344F-W00000000-1

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Подсвечивает строку `implementation`. В чем причина?

Comment: Кручу-верчу-запутать-хочу...

Может быть мы увидим немного кода?

Comment: @Nofate, но мы же можем включить воображение! :)
![asd][1]

[1]: http://minikhaber.files.wordpress.com/2009/07/sunger-bob1.jpg

Comment: Ошибка в 17-й строке. Инфа 146%.

Comment: @Nofate, @teanЫЧ, @Yura Ivanov ошибка исчезла после закрытия и открытия Delphi. Поэтому не стал выкладывать код пока.

Comment: @ivan31, ну спросите у гугля сначала, а? ну куча ресурсов есть про delphi Internal Error. Хэшкод довольно молодой ресурс, чтоб тут были ответы на все вопросы всех факов.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, даже если бы тут были ответы на все вопросы всех факов, то все равно никто не пользовался бы поиском...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сообщение об ошибке Internal Error указывает на то, что компилятор столкнулся с некоторой ситуацией, отличной от синтаксической ошибки, и он не может продолжить компиляцию.

пристань описывает данную проблему [ТУТ](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Resolving_Internal_Errors_%28Delphi%29).
для ленивых перевод [ТАМ](http://www.transl-gunsmoker.ru/2008/11/internal-error-delphi.html)

---

Я сам сталкивался с подобными еррорами, которые возникали на пустом месте (Я мог запустить компилятор, он нормально отработал. После чего еще раз, не меняя код, запустить его, и получить Internal Error). Всегда помогал перезапуск IDE.

---

Ответил только сейчас, ибо в тексте вопроса суть не была указана, а ошибку в шапке читать было лень =/